# Google Spreadsheet Addon - unsubmit pending version

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I have a Google Spreadsheet addon that has been running for a while now.

A few days ago, due to to a change that happened on my company's server side, I submitted a new version to be published. Usually, this takes about 30 minutes. However, this time I got a notice that my update should be reviewed.

I've got 2 issues:
1. It has been days, and the item is still pending review
2. Another back-end change caused my first fix to be insufficient; however, I cannot push a newer version while the current is under review.

My addon is currently *not functional*, so I'm hoping to get a quick resolution.

How can I unsubmit the existing published version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill this form, so your issue can be attended by Google: https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/?hl=en